# My new stove has white spots

Tags: electric-stoves

I recently moved and I have a new cooktop.  White spots have appeared as single wick stains or white bubbles. Does anyone know how I can remove them or make it look better.[image]

Comment: It is worth mentioning that Weiman used to clean it just

Comment: This is a glass cooktop? And did the spots appear after cooking or cleaning?

Comment: I think after cooking yes it’s a glass cooktop

Answer (score 2):

Tap water always contains some dissolved minerals, and those minerals create a visible deposit upon water's evaporation. Those spots look exactly like they were caused by that. Use a bit of white vinegar and apply a bit of gentle scrubbing action and they will go away at instant. Do not use cleaners based on citric acid, as citric acid (unlike the acetic acid within vinegar) is a solid at room temperature, and could leave similar-looking spots.

Comment: Hi, I tried with white vinegar and they didn't take off☹️

Answer (score 0):

Do you live in an area with hard water? This could be calcium spots left over from boiling off water droplets on the stove top. They are harmless.

Regular soap meant to remove grease will not remove them, you need something specific for that, usually based on citric acid. I don't know what the Weiman cleaner you used contains so check that.

Answer (score 0):

First, carefully determine whether the spots are on the surface of the cooktop or a lower level of the cooktop material.  It may be possible to do this using standard cleaning products, a fingernail, or a plastic pan scraper, or even just by inspection under different lighting conditions.

If all else fails, one can in principle determine if the spots are superficial by using an abrasive such as a Magic Eraser, Bar Keepers Friend, or Meguiar's liquid micro-abrasive products (compounds, swirl removers, etc.).  However this route risks introducing fine scratches, so proceed with caution!  In general, rub only *very gently* and test in an inconspicuous area first.  Additionally, do not rub across the lines and circles on the cooktop or you may very well remove them.

If none of the above affects the spots, then they are probably within the cooktop material itself, which would need to be removed and treated or replaced to eliminate them.